# User credentials (id and secret) with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm new to API Gateway and I'm trying to write a REST API that exposes endpoints for users to call. From having worked with other APIs, I know that typically, you receive an ID and a secret that you can then use to access the API programmatically.

I've researched a bit, but so far, I've only found ways to generate access tokens for a limited amount of time (up to 1 hour), but I'd like users to retain their ID and secret permanently.

Any help or pointing to further reading would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would caution that non-expiring access tokens aren't a security best-practice. Most APIs follow an OAuth style pattern where an authentication method returns a authenticated token that the user can then use to access other resources for a limited duration after which re-authentication is required. This ensures that a compromised auth token will only grant the thief a limited usage period.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Amazon API Gateway Custom Authorizers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) which will allow you to implement authentication in whatever manner you'd like to see it work within a Lambda function that's called from api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cognito User Pools with API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) that will allow you to control the user that has access to your API easily.

Walkthrough:

1. Sign up a first-time user to a specified user pool.
2. Sign in a user to the user pool.
3. Get the user's identity token.
4. Call API methods configured with a user pool authorizer, supplying the unexpired token in the Authorization header or another header of your choosing.
5. When the token expires, repeat Step 2-4. Identity tokens provisioned by Amazon Cognito expire within an hour.